# what javascript library exists that allows partial loading of a larger image?

Tags: javascript, image

I am looking for a way to output series of a large image with a specific region that changes over a period of time. Instead of having to reload the large image again and again, I am looking for a more efficient way of swapping out the particular (X,Y) region with an updated graphic. I really don't know what this method is called or what to be searching for in google.

Comment: Stackoverflow is NOT your personal search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break your main image up into blocks that, when laid out next to each other look exactly like one seamless image.  You can then replace one or more individual blocks with a different image URL at any time.

There are several possible names for the general concept.  "Image Tiling" and "Image Slicing" are a couple phrases that come to mind.

This technique is also used sometimes to help large images load better (more so back in slower internet days than today).  Parts of Google maps used to load this way.

Comment: I think Google Maps still works this way.